# Vue Antd Can't change ant-input-suffix style

Tags: vue.js, antd

I would like to change the style of the clear input icon, but can not change it.

```
<a-input placeholder="Basic usage" allowClear />
```

[image]

In my `css`, I use the classname `ant-input-suffix` and write

```
.ant-input-suffix{
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Classname `ant-input-clear-icon` doesn't work either.

What can I do to change it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are running to is probably a specificity ([what is specificity in css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)) problem.

To fix your problem (if it is specificity) you can do:

```
span.ant-input-suffix {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

To better target your elements we would need to see more HTML before giving a concrete answer

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I guess it's not a specificity problem. When i use `f12` and check the elements, I can't even find the style I write for `.ant-input-suffix`. I believe if it's overridden because of specificity, I can still see it in `f12 elements`? 
Here's an example of my code if you'd like to take a look.
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-cherry-g34v9?file=/src/App.vue